# XSLT - Adding a class to something with a class?

Tags: xslt

When using XSLT how do I apply a class to an element which already has a class? The way I'm doing it it replaces the class that is already present? How would I add the class in addition to the existing class? My code is as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="data[@alias = 'off'] = 1">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">off</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The other way around:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">
  <xsl:if test="data[@alias = 'off'] = 1">off </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">active </xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Note the extra space I put after every attribute value. The XSLT processor will trim the trailing space from the attribute value on its own, so no need to do complicated space handling.

Comment: Note that in terms of spaces, the Qt implementation will include the newline characters if written in this way. If you add newlines within the `<xsl:if` tag, however, you're good.

Comment: @Alexis BTW, literal newlines inside an attribute value are normalized into space when the document is parsed again. So despite the uglier look newlines would even work as token delimiters here.

Answer (score 9):

you can concatenate the current class attribute value with the new one:

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@class,' active')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I tried that with the Qt xmlpatterns tool and it does not work (nothing happens). Too bad, because the other method, I cannot use in my situation!

Comment: Does not work for me. Just replaces the class, no concatenation happening.

Comment: Checked again: @class is empty, that's why. How do I get a value into @class?

Comment: @Ralf it would work if your input tag already had a class attribute: `<my-tag class="beautiful">...</my-tag>` then this code would see `"beautifyl"` as the value of `@class`.